# htaccess redirect based on url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to write the htaccess rule based on

```
http://mysite.com/http://google.com    -> http://google.com

http://mysite.com/http://facebook.com  -> http://facebook.com
```

should redirect with 302 to that url ( except the main file index.php ), so the actual referrer would be hidden,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(https?://[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

Comment: That works great, but how to implement redirect also without http:// ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Change RewriteCond to this: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+((?:https?://)?[^\s]+) [NC]`

Comment: Hi,but it shows the referrer, how to hide it ? example http://vladvipstar.ru/http://www.stardrifter.org/cgi-bin/ref.cgi ,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I make the assumption that all your links will start with a protocol then the following will work:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(https?)://(.*)$      $1://$2 [NC,L,R=302]
```