# Need Help. I need to direct incoming traffic based on Referer

Tags: java, javascript, referer

So here's the deal.

I have a public page, that I cannot restrict to members only, that I need to check the incoming referer URL, and route traffic if coming from the proper domain.
All other traffic, to be routed to an off site landing page.

E Commerce sales promotion between 2 companies, I only want to allow those who are coming in from the approved url.

I would've tried to do this with robots.txt, but in this case I don't have access to that file (thanks to the CMS I'm using).

I am pretty much forced to do this with Java.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: java or javascript? What language does the server use, as that would be the appropriate place to do this sort of thing.

Comment: FYI, the Referer HTTP header can be spoofed easily, though you probably won't care about that that much.

Answer (score 0):

Referer in on-page Javascript is a very insecure way of doing things - for a start it will be world-readable. If security is not a prime concern but you want something better than JS, I'd head to the web server and do it in .htaccess or the equivalent [Question #10171698](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171698/htaccess-redirect-based-on-url)

Comment: yea, I actually meant to say htaccess in the question, vs robots... I dont have access to that file on this CMS.  Its my biggest annoyance with this host (NS)

Comment: Quick and dirty then is just to use document.referrer and do a string comparison followed by a window.location.href to redirect. But it's not pretty and it's not secure. Do you know that will always be a referrer?

Comment: Actually - [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581503/how-to-redirect-page-and-js-using-javascript-on-external-domain-based-on-referer?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

From Java use `String referer = request.getHeader("referer");` where request is an instance of type `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`.

As others have noted, spoofing the referer is trivial and shouldn't be your only form of security.